# Why is there a big difference in profiles returned by "sfdx force:source:pull" and "sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve"?

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx, profile

I have a project with a scratch org created using some profiles that date from the MDAPI days. The profiles look good in the org.

Having added some record types, I expected:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

to do a good job of pulling the profiles back. But the profiles are about 1/3 the size of the original ones, and are missing many elements such as `applicationVisibilities` and `recordTypeVisibilities` needed for the source to be pushed in our CI (Continuous Integration) environment.

Resorting to:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve
```

and doing some manual cut and pasting of just the profiles appears to solve the problem.

What is your experience in this area? Is there something I have missed here (release notes, known issues)? I am using the latest version of SFDX and the plugins.

**PS**

Just added a field and did another `sfdx force:source:pull` with this result:

```
Element                  Pull Result
*******                  ***********
applicationVisibilities  missing
classAccesses            missing
fieldPermissions         expected 1862, but only 1368
layoutAssignments        missing
objectPermissions        missing
pageAccesses             missing
recordTypeVisibilities   missing
tabVisibilities          missing
userPermissions          OK
userLicense              OK
```

Comment: Application visibility might be related to W-2881774 ("Unable to retrieve AppMenu.Switcher)? But I don't see how record type visibility could be affected. Out of curiosity, what is missing from those?

Comment: Hi @RenatoOliveira, I've added what I'm seeing to the question in a PS. Very weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the [Metadata Coverage Report and searched for Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/45/Profile/issues). It showed up two Known Issues for Profile:

- [sfdx force:source:pull does not fetch the changes on Profile for record type permission change](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ATbqQAG)

  > If "sfdx force:source:pull" command is run to fetch the profile details after changing the assigned record types, we see that the changes do not get pulled.
- [sfdx force:source:pull loses Field Level Security](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000nZCLQA2)

  > For SFDX pull requests, for field changes, pulled profiles lose previous Field Level Security from profile xml

Those might explain some of the dependencies that you are encountering.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - a useful page in general too. Looks like for now it has to be `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve`.

Comment: FYI force:source:retrieve AND fource:mdapi:retrieve (on a sandbox) are also producing the same results. I believe this started happening after my CLI was updated from 7.91.x. Right now I'm on v7.94.3 and the problem is still there.